# renaming a bunch of variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After a left_join I have variables `var1.x var2.x` ... and `var1.y var2.y` . I would like to rename them to `var1_tot var2_tot` and `var1_part var2_part`. I can do this but combining `names` and string replacement functions. Can this be done as part pf a `dplyr` chain by using `dplyr`'s `rename` function and `ends_with`?

Answer (score 6):

Like this? `dt` is an example data frame. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- data_frame(var1.x = 1:3, var2.x = 4:6, var1.y = 7:9, var2.y = 10:12)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with(".x")), funs(sub(".x", "_tot", .))) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with(".y")), funs(sub(".y", "_part", .)))
dt2
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  var1_tot var2_tot var1_part var2_part
     <int>    <int>     <int>     <int>
1        1        4         7        10
2        2        5         8        11
3        3        6         9        12
```

Comment: Instead of `sub` I tried using `str_replace` from `stringr` and it dit not work.

Comment: @ErichNeuwirth Did you adjust the order of the arguments to work with `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

`rename_at(mydf,vars(matches(".x")),function(x) str_replace(x,".x","_total"))`

Answer (score -1):

In fact

```
mydf %>% rename_at(vars(ends_with(".x")),funs(str_replace(.,".x","_total")))
```

did work

Comment: Your original question is about `rename` and `ends_with` from `dplyr`. Is there any particular reason you need to use `str_replace` from `stringr`? Replacing `sub` with `str_replace` does not fundamentally change the nature of my solution.